# If localStorage item set then load page; else redirect

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am creating a simple webapp that needs to check your age and agree to terms.
To save on data transfers I want to use `localStorage`.

Problem is when I create my link and call my `onclick` function the app loads both the adult content in the current window and the age verification in a new window and when you confirm your age the app goes into an endless loop loading the adult content in the new window.

The adult content is two pages; one is a form and the other a results page.
I need to add the code to those as well to redirect if `localStorage.getItem()` value is `null`.

But I first need to make sure you verify before I can go to that step.

This is what I have so far:

```
<a href="age.html" target="new" onclick="verCheck()">Order Form</a></li>
```

```
function verCheck() {
    var LS = localStorage.getItem('ageVerified');

    if (LS == "True") {
        window.location.assign("/orderform.html")
    } else {
        alert("Error")
        window.location.assign("/about.html")
    }
}
```

Comment: You do realize that anyone (or should I say any child) with a basic understanding of Javascript can simply set `localStorage.ageVerified` themselves by using Firebug or a similar browser console, right?  If you are serious about enforcing this check, you *must* do it server-side every-time; any client-side tech you rely on (local storage, cookies, etc.) are by definition editable by the client/end user.  Besides "to save on data transfers" is kind of a silly goal nowadays anyway; if people have enough bandwidth to download porn, they have enough to make an extra age verification server call.

Comment: as @machineghost said this is extremely insecure and you should not do it.

Comment: its not porn its alcohol related its just to eliminate any legal ramifications by not asking for it. and in a webapp it is important if the client wants to save on bandwidth its not a computer is mobile phone app

Comment: `its alcohol related its just to eliminate any legal ramifications` .. I would assume that means you need to make sure you verify the age server side or you end up providing alcohol to minors?

Comment: nevermind. this is not to purchase alcohol directly. just related. thanks for the help

Comment: @MPMullally: Ah, I see. That's slightly different then alright.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.assign` loads the document, to reload the page just assign the url to `window.location.replace`

```
function verCheck(){
    var LS = localStorage.getItem('ageVerified');
    if (LS == "True") {
        window.location.assign("/orderform.html")
    } else{
        alert("Error")
        window.location.replace("/about.html");
    }
}
```